# Very simple in memory storage

Tags: postgresql, redis, in-memory-database, nosql

I need some very simple storage to keep data, before it will be added to PostgreSQL. Currently, I have web application that collects data from clients. This data is not very important. Application collects about 50 kb of data (simple string) from one client. It will be collect about 2GB data per hour. 
This data is not needed ASAP and it's nothing if it will be lost. 
Is there a existing solution to store it in memory for a while (~ 1 hour), and then write it all in PostgreSQL. I don't need to query it in any way. 
I can use Redis, probably, but Redis is too complex for this task. 
I can write something by myself, but this tool will be must to handle many requests to store data (maybe about 100 per second) and existing solution may be better.

Thanks,
Dmitry

Comment: It is unclear what you are actually asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not plan to work this data operatively so why do you want to store it in memory? You may create `UNLOGGED` table and store data in this table.

Look at the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtable.html) for details:

> UNLOGGED
>
> If specified, the table is created as an unlogged table. Data written
>   to unlogged tables is not written to the write-ahead log, which makes 
>   them considerably faster than ordinary tables.
>   However, they are not crash-safe: an unlogged table is automatically
>   truncated after a crash or unclean shutdown. The contents of an
>   unlogged table are also not replicated to standby servers. Any indexes
>   created on an unlogged table are automatically unlogged as well;
>   however, unlogged GiST indexes are currently not supported and cannot
>   be created on an unlogged table.

Comment: It's much faster to access data stored in memory. If I will store data in memory it will be much faster to write it to PostgreSQL, I guess. I need to write it approximately every hour. It's not very small time. And it's faster to write data in large portions. So, I thought it will be better to write it from memory and in large portions, than in small pieces.

Comment: As I can see in different benchmarks, write in UNLOGGED table is ~2 times faster than normal requests. But I want to use advantages of mass update in transactions what may be ~100 times faster. So, I'm not sure that  UNLOGGED table is best possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Storing data in memory sounds like caching to me. So, *if you are using Java*, I would recommend [Guava Cache](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) to you!

It seems to fit all your requirements, e.g. setting an expiry delay, handling the data once it is evicted from the cache:

```
    private Cache<String, Object> yourCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .expireAfterWrite(2, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .removalListener(notification -> {
            // store object in DB
        })
        .build();
```